# Empty columns when inserted into into df from another df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to add from df5 columns to df_prog. But for some reason they remain empty. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. Code:

df5['Kol1_1Y']

```
223520    14.0
223521    65.0
223522    13.0
223523    39.0
223524    13.0
223525     3.0
223526    10.0
223527    19.0
223528    16.0
223529    29.0
Name: Kol1_1Y, dtype: float64

df_prog['Kol1_1Y'] = df5['Kol1_1Y']
df_prog['Kol2_1Y'] = df5['Kol2_1Y']
df_prog['Kol1_3M'] = df5['Kol1_3M']
df_prog['Kol2_3M'] = df5['Kol2_3M']
df_prog.to_excel("C:\python\progGB.xlsx")

df_prog

0           RESPR   PREVPR  Kol1_1Y Kol2_1Y Kol1_3M Kol2_3M
0   0.4944  0.4944  1.4894  NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   0.7073  0.7073  3.2020  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   0.3965  0.3965  -0.3989 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   0.4501  0.4501  -0.1826 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   0.0271  0.0271  -6.1202 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   0.2488  0.2488  -2.8447 NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   0.5190  0.5190  0.0176  NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   0.6667  0.6667  2.2334  NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   0.7708  0.7708  4.5216  NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   0.7074  0.7074  2.9906  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas `=` assignment checking both `index` and `columns`. In your case, columns is matched, but index is different. Therefore, it assigns all `NaN`. To ignore index and columns, you need assigning from numpy ndarray such as:

```
df_prog['Kol1_1Y'] = df5['Kol1_1Y'].values
df_prog['Kol2_1Y'] = df5['Kol2_1Y'].values
df_prog['Kol1_3M'] = df5['Kol1_3M'].values
df_prog['Kol2_3M'] = df5['Kol2_3M'].values
```